# SQL Server UPDATE statement not updating rows matching constraints

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-update, jtds

If I read this question I would immediately think "some idiot asking for help before doing any research himself".  While it remains to be seen whether or not the "idiot" designation is correct, I can assure you this isn't my first rodeo and I've beat my head against this wall for 40-80 hours.

**Short Story:** My system executes 1 update statement four times passing in four different parameter values.  Based on the constraints each execution should modify approximately 50,000 rows.  However while 2 of the executions modify the expected number of rows, the other two only update 201 rows.

**Disclaimer:**
In an effort to convince you I'm not a noob, who is updating one Database and then wondering why the records in a different DB aren't updated.

- I'm a programmer with 15+ years experience, specializing in systems in which batch processing performance is critical
- My level of expertise with SQL Server is way below the typical DBA, but considerably higher than the typical developer
- As I mentioned above I have spent 40-80 hours researching this issue
- I am out of ideas

**Long Story:**

The table in question looks something like:

- MyPkCol - BIGINT - Not involved in UPDATE statement. Only column in clustered index
- MyForeignKeyCol1 - BIGINT - Pointer to another table which is cleared by Update
- MyIntCol - INT - Basic data which is cleared by Update
- MyForeignKeyCol2 - BIGINT - Pointer to another table which is cleared by Update and is the only constraint

There is a non-clustered index which only contains `MyForeignKeyCol1` (no includes).

There is another non-clustered index which only contains `MyForeignKeyCol2` (no includes).

There is a foreign key for `MyForeignKeyCol1` and another on `MyForeignKeyCol2`.

The update statement is:

```
UPDATE T1 
SET MyForeignKeyCol1 = NULL, 
    MyForeignKeyCol2 = NULL, 
    MyIntCol = NULL 
WHERE MyForeignKeyCol2 = ?
```

The problem is highly inconsistent. I've ran the process 200-300 times and the problem has only occurred 3 times to date.

In the most recent occurrence, the table in question contained about 200,000 records. 50,000 contained a value of 123 in `MyForeignKeyCol2`, 50,000 contained a value of 345 in `MyForeignKeyCol2`, 50,000 contained a value of 567 in `MyForeignKeyCol2`, and 50,000 contained a value of 789 in `MyForeignKeyCol2`.

The process executes the Update statement 4 times passing in parameters of 123, 345, 567 and 789. Each of the 4 Updates is performed in a separate transaction.  The database driver reports that the statements modified the following number of records:

- 50,000
- 201
- 201
- 50,000

The state of the DB shows that 49,799 records remain with `MyForeignKeyCol2=345` and another 49,799 records remain with `MyForeignKeyCol2=567`.

The database contains no triggers.

One of my first theories is that at the moment the UPDATE was executed the `MyForeignKeyCol2` column on the skipped records contained some value other than 345 or 567, then later after the UPDATE something is populating the column with those values. After many hours of research I'm 99.99% sure that is not the case.

Could this type of behavior be caused by something like a corrupt Index or out of date statistics?

In my experience the DB is the most reliable part of any system I'm involved in, and thus the last thing I ever suspect, but that is the only theory that I have left.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can check database for corruption using `DBCC CHECKDB`. You should check if there are other processes that update the same table. You can add a trigger to this table to log each attempt to update the table and then review the logs and confirm that there is another process. SQL Server **is** quite reliable, it is very unlikely that its `UPDATE` code has such bug.

Comment: On a second thought, you should also add auditing triggers for `DELETE` and `INSERT`, because another process may delete some rows before your main `UPDATE` and then insert them back after your main `UPDATE`. If that another process doesn't wrap these two statements in a transaction, with a good timing you can get the results that you see.

Answer (score 2):

I still do not have the full answer, but I now understand enough to mark it as answered to avoid others wasting their time on it.  I will provide the full answer once I have it.

NOTE: I failed to mention that this is a Java application.

It appears that another thread (a Thread servicing some UI activity) it getting a handle on this java.sql.Statement object and calling Statement.setMaxRows(201) on it between the first and second UPDATES.  Then presumably calling it again passing in a large number between the third and forth UPDATES.

I've always had the impression that setMaxRows only impacted SELECT statements and the javadoc for that method supports that misconception (IMO).  However I now understand that it will also impact UPDATE, DELETES and INSERTS (not 100% sure about INSERTS).  Setting this field to 201 results in the JTDS driver sending a "SET ROWCOUNT 201" command to SQL Server prior to the UPDATE statement, which results in SQL Server limiting the number of rows effected by the UPDATE to 201.

Now the remaining question is "how did the other thread get a handle on that Connection"?  We use a Connection Pooling Library and we also have another library which helps with DB transaction management.  I'll avoid naming them at this point, b/c the most likely culprit is our code (as always).

Thanks to everyone who spent their valuable time to read this very long question.

**FINAL ANSWER!!!**
It is a bug in the latest version (1.3.1) of the JTDS Driver.  https://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/bugs/726/

Thanks again for anyone who took time to review my question!

Comment: Oh dear, that means you might have some serious data integrity issues already.

Comment: Found during QA thankfully.  It's not easy to reproduce, but it wouldn't be too uncommon with enough users hammering on the system.